# How to copy directories under the root from the remote host?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am trying to copy dirs and files under the root on the remote host, using non-root user, which one actually doesn`t have access to this folders. So I need something like sudo while copying.

Sample command:

```
scp user@<host>:<path_to_folder_under_the_root> .
```

I cannot use root@ cause I have not the root keys local. Is there any possible ways to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What users do you have? What SSH access is possible? Can you use `ssh user@<host>` and then `sudo scp ... user@other_host:some/path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you do have `sudo` access on the remote host, instead of using `scp` you can use `ssh` and `tar`:

```
ssh user@<host> sudo tar -C <path_to_folder_under_the_root> -cf . | tar -xf-
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is `rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync"`.

Comment: this shouldn't be an answer but rather a comment to @larsks 's post. Don't forget to vote/accept the answer if you want